# dependency tree on maven

Tags: git, maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

How does maven resolve dependency tree?

I ask this as I get 3 different dependency trees published in as many environments - though the versions of the components(those that get published) are the same.

For some components ,the dependencies simply get skipped to be mentioned in one environment,while not in another.

What causes maven to suppress mentioning dependencies?
**I am using maven 3.2.1**

Comment: How do you create the dependency tree ?

Comment: mvn compile dependency:tree

Answer (score 2):

Can you try running `mvn dependency:tree` instead of `mvn compile dependency:tree`? I am running the command and getting the output as expected. Thanks.

P.S: I wanted to add this as a comment, but can't because of my rep.

Comment: You could turn this from a comment into a proper if brief answer if you [edit] it a little.  E.g.  something like *I was able to reproduce your problem using the command `mvn compile dependency:tree`.  However, the command `mvn dependency:tree` generated the correct results.*  (Assuming that's true of course!)